# POSIX shell comments in command-substitutions

Tags: bash, sh, posix, language-lawyer, busybox

I'm writing a shell, and am getting unexpected parsing from both bash, dash, and busybox's ash:

```
echo "`echo a #`"
```

prints `a`, however

```
echo "$(echo a #)"
```

gives an error about missing a closing `)`.

How is a comment in a command-substitution parsed according to POSIX?
So, for the commands:

```
echo "`echo a #`"
```

and

```
echo "$(echo a #)"
```

Will the shell parse the comment as extending to the end of the command substitution, or to the end of the line?
Also, will the shell parse it differently if the command substitutions are not in double quotes?
Finally, are there any other constructs (either in POSIX or bash) where a comment can start inside quotes like this?

Comment: `ksh` and `zsh` exhibit the same behavior. I have no explanation, but here's the link to the relevant part of the POSIX spec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03

Comment: Quoting the `#` to avoid any possibility of it being treated as a comment character would avoid the problem.

Comment: @chepner unless the intent was to add a comment inside a command substitution for documentation purposes - in which case there is no satisfactory answer here.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn Command substitutions can be split across multiple lines. Put a newline between the `#` and the `)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Posix ([Shell&Utilities, §2.6.3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)), `` "`echo a #`" `` is undefined (implying that it should not be used):

> The search for the matching backquote shall be satisfied by the first unquoted non-escaped backquote; during this search, if a non-escaped backquote is encountered **within a shell comment**, … undefined results occur. (emphasis added)

However, the `$(` command substitution marker is terminated by the "first matching `)`"; the implication (made explicit by examples in the [Rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03), Note 1) is that the matching `)` cannot be inside of a shell comment, here-doc or quoted string.

The quotes surrounding the command substitution are not relevant in either case (although, of course, "undefined results" could be different in the quoted case, since they are undefined.)

In bash and certain other shells, comments could also be present inside process substitution (eg., `<(…)`); however, process substitution cannot be quoted.

---

#### Notes:

1. Thanks to [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), who included this link in a comment.